# Unable to retrieve single EC2 instance id from multiple ids for ALB module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create Application Load Balancer(ALB) for which setting target type as instance.I've created ec2 ,ALB ,route53 ,acm modules along with supporting resources. Following are the code files :

**alb.tf**

```
module "ec2_instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"

  for_each = toset(["one", "two"])

  name = "bcr-templates-instance-${each.key}"

  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.bcr-templates-ami.id
  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name}"
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.vpc.default_security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = module.vpc.public_subnets[0]

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}


module "alb" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/alb/aws"
  version = "~> 8.0"

  name = "bcr-templates-alb"

  load_balancer_type  = "application"

  vpc_id              = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnets             = module.vpc.public_subnets
  security_groups     = [module.vpc.default_security_group_id]
 

  security_group_rules = {
    ingress_all_http = {
      type        = "ingress"
      from_port   = 80
      to_port     = 80
      protocol    = "tcp"
      description = "HTTP web traffic"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress_all_icmp = {
      type        = "ingress"
      from_port   = -1
      to_port     = -1
      protocol    = "icmp"
      description = "ICMP"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    egress_all = {
      type        = "egress"
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      protocol    = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }

  target_groups = [
    {
      name_prefix      = "h1"
      backend_protocol = "HTTP"
      backend_port     = 80
      target_type      = "instance"
      targets = {
        ec2_target = {
          target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance,0)).id)
          port = 80
        }
        my_other_target = {
          target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance,1)).id)
          port = 8080
        }
      }
    }
  ]

  https_listeners = [
    {
      port               = 443
      protocol           = "HTTPS"
      certificate_arn    = module.acm.acm_certificate_arn
      target_group_index = 0
    }
  ]

  http_tcp_listeners = [
    {
      port               = 80
      protocol           = "HTTP"
      target_group_index = 0
    },
    {
      port        = 81
      protocol    = "HTTP"
      action_type = "forward"
      forward = {
        target_groups = [
          {
            target_group_index = 0
            weight             = 100
          },
          {
            target_group_index = 1
            weight             = 0
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      port        = 82
      protocol    = "HTTP"
      action_type = "redirect"
      redirect = {
        port        = "443"
        protocol    = "HTTPS"
        status_code = "HTTP_301"
      }
    },
    {
      port        = 83
      protocol    = "HTTP"
      action_type = "fixed-response"
      fixed_response = {
        content_type = "text/plain"
        message_body = "Fixed message"
        status_code  = "200"
      }
    },
  ]

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "ami" {
```

```
description = "AMI ID that was used to create the instance"
```

```
 value          = toset([ for v in module.ec2_instance : v.ami ])
```

```
}
```

```
output "id" {
```

```
description = "The ID of the instance"
```

```
value           = values(module.ec2_instance)[*].id
}
```

**Terraform version is 1.4.6**

I'm trying to use ec2 module's output value in ALB module to fetch single ec2 instance id but i'm getting following error :

```
Error: Not enough function arguments

  on alb.tf line 274, in module "alb":
 274:           target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance,0)).id)
    ├────────────────
    │ while calling element(list, index)
    │ module.ec2_instance is a map of object

Function "element" expects 2 argument(s). Missing value for "index".

Error: Not enough function arguments

  on alb.tf line 278, in module "alb":
 278:           target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance,1)).id)
    ├────────────────
    │ while calling element(list, index)
    │ module.ec2_instance is a map of object

Function "element" expects 2 argument(s). Missing value for "index".
```

Could someone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure your issue is:

`target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance,1)).id)`

Your index is placed in the tolist function, not in the element function.

This should work:
 `target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance),1).id)`

However the core issue is that your module.ec2_instance is devised as a map of objects, which you can't convert directly to a list.

Your two options are:

1. Access the values directly: `module.ec2_instance["one"].id`
2. Use the `values` function to convert the map into a list of values `element(values(module.ec2_instance),0).id`

Comment: Modified target_id as suggested above but still getting error :
Error: Invalid function argument

  on alb.tf line 258, in module "alb":
 258:           target_id = (element(tolist(module.ec2_instance),1).id)
    ├────────────────
    │ while calling tolist(v)
    │ module.ec2_instance is a map of object
Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert map of object to list of any
single type.

Comment: You can just directly access the outputs like this: module.ec2_instance["one"].id, and module.ec2_instance["two"].id

Comment: Many Thanks ! @alex067   Both new options solves the problem